# How to assert if an element exists in angular?

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-directive, chai, karma-mocha

I am writing a spec for a directive. As part of the testing, I need to assert if an element with a class exists inside my root directive component.

I have tried the following.

```
it('should have a loading div container', function() {
            var loadingDivContainer = element.find('.loading-div');
            expect(loadingDivContainer).to.exist;
        });
```

But this seems to pass in all the condition. I am using the following tech.

Angular 1.x, mocha, chai,

Comment: expect(loadingDivContainer.length).not.to.eql(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

loadingDivContainer would be an empty array if it found no results, or have length if it did have results. So check length:

```
expect(loadingDivContainer.length).to.be(1);
```

or

```
expect(loadingDivContainer.length).not.to.be(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

We found the answer.

```
var loadingDivContainer = element[0].querySelectorAll('.loading-div');
expect(loadingDivContainer.length).to.be(1);
```

Comment: You should accept Brant's answer and, if needed, include your updated selector as a comment. Poor taste (in my opinion, of course) to post an answer which is essentiatlly the same as an earlier answer.

Comment: Thank you Lex, and I agree.

Comment: Yes is true but we wanted a different answer the point was on the element[0].querySelectorAll('.loading-div') because the find cannot see classes. Anyway is both true